# EasyMock verifying calls to mock in tearDown method after verify finished

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, easymock

I am seeing inconsistent behaviour in EasyMock tests that I don't understand.

My first test passes..

```
public class MockATest {

   private final AtomicLong aMock = createStrictMock(AtomicLong.class);

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
      aMock.set(101L);
   }

   @After
   public void tearDown() {
      aMock.set(999L);
   }

   @Test
   public void testA() {
      reset(aMock);
      replay(aMock);
      // TODO : test stuff here
      verify(aMock);
   }

}
```

.. but my second test fails ...

```
public class MockBTest {

   private final List<Long> bMock = createStrictMock(List.class);

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
      bMock.add(101L);
   }

   @After
   public void tearDown() {
      bMock.add(999L);
   }

   @Test
   public void testB() {
      reset(bMock);
      replay(bMock);
      // TODO : test stuff here
      verify(bMock);
   }

}
```

The failure reason is

> Unexpected method call List.add(999)

I have 2 questions really...

1. Why is the behaviour different for the 2 tests?
2. Why is the add(999L) that happens in the tearDown method is being verified after the verification in the testB method has already fully completed?

(I know I can make this work by adding another reset(bMock) in after the verify(bMock) but I am not sure whether this is just avoiding the issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why is the behaviour different for the 2 tests?

Because `AtomicLong.set` is typed `void AtomicLong.set(long)` so it's a void method. The recording is fine. However, `List.add` is typed `boolean List.add(E)` so it's not a void method. The correct way to record a non-void method is to do `expect(list.add(101L)).andReturn(true)`.

2. Why is the add(999L) that happens in the tearDown method is being verified after the verification in the testB method has already fully completed?

Because it never goes in `testB()`. EasyMock throws an error on the call to `bMock.add(101L)` in `setUp()` so it goes directly to the `tearDown` which fail as well and hides to exception from `setUp()`.

Comment: Doh - of course!  Thank you Henri for seeing the obvious.